# node.js call ws.send from controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

i want to send a websocket, using express-ws out from a different controller, not by route and I have the following code in the server.js:

```
var SocketController = require('./routes/ws.routes');
var app  = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.ws('/', SocketController.socketFunction);
```

the SocketController looks like that:

```
exports.socketFunction = function (ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        ws.send("hello");
    });
}
```

Is it possible to call the

```
ws.send()
```

event from another controller? How do i get the `ws` object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to store your sockets in memory. To access stored sockets from different modules, you can store references for these sockets in a separate module.

For example, you can create a module socketCollection that stores all the active sockets.

socketCollection.js:

```
exports.socketCollection = [];
```

You can import this module where you define your web socket server:

```
var socketCollection = require('./socketCollection');
var SocketController = require('./routes/ws.routes');
var app  = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

expressWs.getWss().on('connection', function(ws) {
  socketCollection.push({
    id: 'someRandomSocketId',
    socket: ws,
  });
});

app.ws('/', SocketController.socketFunction);
```

Now every time new client connects to the server, it's reference will be saved to 'socketCollection'
You can access these clients from any module by importing this array

```
var socketCollection = require('./socketCollection');
var ws = findSocket('someRandomSocketId', socketCollection);

var findSocket = function(id, socketCollection) {
   var result  = socketCollection.filter(function(x){return x.id == id;} );
   return result ? result[0].socket : null;
};
```

Comment: a great, thanks! And if i want to send to all, i do something like this: collection.forEach((data,index) => {
        data.on('message', function(msg) {
            data.send("hello from node");
        });
    })

Comment: Do I need a socket.on for every single socket?

Comment: Not on socket... Register the event once with socket server... And it will be called every time when new client connects...